# TSQL: select featured products in a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In my DB I have the products table (ID int, ... , Sponsored bool)
My goal is to be able to get 20 random products from the table. Sponsored products must be returned first. If there are less than 20 sponsored products I sould get random non sponsored products till 20 items.

Can I do this in one select? Or if not one select as efficient as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @a table (ID int, Sponsored bit)

insert @a values(1, 1)
insert @a values(2, 0)
insert @a values(3, 0)

select top 20 * from @a order by sponsored desc, newid()
```